# Do the Adeles Split?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, homological-algebra

I asked this question about a week ago here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288955/splitting-the-exact-sequence-of-the-idele-class-group, but got no answer so I thought I'd aske here and see if I can get some help.

I was wondering if there are any conditions on a number field $K$ such that $$0 \longrightarrow K^{\times} \longrightarrow \mathbb{A}_{K}^{\times} \longrightarrow C_K \longrightarrow 0, $$ is a splits as  a sequence of multiplicative abelian groups (here I have done the usual diagonal embedding of $K^{\times}$ into $\mathbb{A}_{K}^{\times}$)

I thought about looking at $H^{2}(C_K,K^{\times})$, but I'm not quite sure how to compute it.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have a good argument right now, but I am pretty sure, that the answer is never. But there is something called strong approximation. Probably this is sufficient for your application.

Comment: Assume $K\ne\mathbf{Q}$ (splits for $\mathbf{Q}$). For any countably infinite direct product $G$ of finite cyclic groups, assume (H): there's no nontrivial homomorphism $G\rightarrow\mathbf{Z}$. If $r:\mathbf{A}^{\times}_K\rightarrow K^{\times}$ is a retraction and $r'$ its composite to $K^{\times}/\mu_K$ (torsion-free with no infinitely divisible elements $\ne 1$!), by (H) and "divisors" and the unit theorem $r'$ is trivial on `$\prod_{v|\infty}K_v^{\times} \times \prod_{v\nmid\infty} O_{K,v}^{\times}$`, so $r'(O_K^{\times})=1$. But $r(O_K^{\times})=O_K^{\times}$, so $K$ is imag. quadratic.

Comment: @Marc Palm: It does split for $K = \mathbf{Q}$, since every rational idele admits a unique $\mathbf{Q}^{\times}$-multiple whose archimedean part is positive and finite part is everywhere an integral unit.

Comment: I am confused. the finite part is not unique. strong approximation holds for any open subgroup.

Comment: @Marc: Strong approximation has nothing to do with (discontinuous) splittings. Consider any $a \in \mathbf{A}^{\times}_{\mathbf{Q}}$ and the finitely many finite places $v$ such that $a_v$ is not an integral unit.  Let $p_v$ be the residue characteristic at $v$ and $n_v = {\rm{ord}}_v(a_v)$, so $q(a) = \prod_v p_v^{n_v} \in \mathbf{Q}^{\times}_{>0}$ depends multiplicatively on $a$ and $a/q(a)$ is an integral unit at all finite places. Let $e(a)$ be the sign of $a_{\infty}/q(a)$, so $a \mapsto e(a)q(a)$ is a retraction of $\mathbf{Q}^{\times}\rightarrow\mathbf{A}^{\times}_{\mathbf{Q}}$.

Comment: For imaginary quadratic $K$ with class number coprime to $\#\mu_K$ there are (lots of) splittings. We treat $h_K=1$ and $\mu_K$ of order 2 ($\mathbf{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_3)$ go similarly). Since $\mathbf{A}^{\times}_K$ is the pushout of $j:\mu_2 \rightarrow K_{\infty}^{\times} \times \prod_{v\nmid\infty}O_{K,v}^{\times}$ along $\mu_2 \rightarrow K^{\times}$, we have to split $j$. Project to $k(v)^{\times}$ for $v\nmid 2\infty$ with $-1$ not a square mod $v$. Then $\mu_2 \rightarrow k(v)^{\times}/(k(v)^{\times})^2$ is an isomorphism, and its inverse provides the desired splitting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.:) You should make your comments into an answer though. 

Comment: Thank you. I'm just wondering what you mean by $\mu_{K}$? I dont think ive seen this notation.

Comment: should mean=the roots of unity